# How do I write validation statement to require a day of the week?

Tags: list, calculated-column-formula, date-time, validation, column-validation

I have a field in a custom list called "WeekOf". I have a default statement that populates the date as the following Monday, but some people are entering for future weeks and then add a start date other than a Monday.

What statement should I put in the column validation to require a Monday?

I'd just figure it out myself, but the client wants it fixed asap.

Comment: Do you want to allow only next Monday or any date which has day as monday?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your users to enter only future Monday's then try using below formula:

```
=IF(AND(TEXT(WEEKDAY([Date Column]), "dddd") = "Monday", [Date Column] > Today()), true, false)
```

If you want your users to enter current as well as future Monday's then try using below formula:

```
=IF(AND(TEXT(WEEKDAY([Date Column]), "dddd") = "Monday", [Date Column] >= Today()), true, false)
```

If you want your users to enter any Monday (Past, current or future) then use below formula:

```
=IF(TEXT(WEEKDAY([Forecast Release Date]), "dddd") = "Monday", true, false)
```

Comment: The third option worked perfectly when I entered it into the List Validation Settings and changed the column name to match. Thanks, Ganesh!

Comment: Great, Glad it worked for you. Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.